# Failed to determine a suitable driver class when trying connect with MySQL db on Docker and Spring Boot app

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, docker-compose

I have dockerized MySQL which runs on port 3307, there is all configuration on docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=my_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user_pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

But problem is that the Spring app is running outside of the Docker and when I run my application I've got error:

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

And there is also configuration of connection with db on application.yml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/my_db?serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I also tried expose ports without 127.0.0.1 and connect by localhost but this doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you `application.yml` file isn't being read?

Comment: That was the problem, I forgot set profile in Intellij > Edit Configuration > Active profiles :|

Comment: @DanielScott I have specified the application.yaml and when. I run my app it states that the profile which I've specified is active, but still throws same error, what could be the problem?